# Display for Topic Request Dismiss vote?

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-topics, documentation-proposals

I just dismissed a topic ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/topic-requests/5081)) because it already exists. Everything fine so far, but after linking the existing topic and clicking ok, *nothing happened* - at least not visible. I wasn't sure if it worked and repeated the procedure, resulting in a "You already voted ..." message.

Can't we get feedback, like:

- after voting a "you voted to dismiss this topic, x Persons have to approve" or something similar
- when visiting the request, show a message I already requested to close it (similar to the notice i get when visiting a topic where I have a pending change or the boxes for improvement requests)