# How do I see which topic proposals I've provided a dismiss vote on or commented on?

Tags: support, documentation

I have a feature request and would like to provide data based on my experience, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. Is there a way to see which documentation topic requests I have either commented on or provided a dismiss vote on?

The documentation tab in my profile doesn't seem to contain either of these actions.

Comment: related to [my question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330402/display-for-topic-request-dismiss-vote)